# Email validation, Java Script. Yii framework

Tags: php, html, yii

I have been trying to come up with method for validating email. to check whether entered email is valid or not? but till now came up with nothing. I just dont wnat fro eamil fromat to be valid but also needd to check entered email exists or not. I am working on yii framework, last time on larvel I succeeded but here I am lost. Any suggestions ??

Comment: What have you tired? You are tying to validate it with Yii?

Comment: Did you check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778326/how-to-validate-email-and-email-already-exist-or-not-check-in-yii-framwork ?

Comment: yes, I am trying to validate with yii

Comment: in model
public function rules()
 {

return array(
     array('email','email'),
array('email','unique'  ,'message' => 'already exists'),

}

}